# What is the best strategy to scrape more than one page simultaneously?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, express

I followed the example

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-node-js-and-jquery/comment-page-1/

and it worked very well.

But in my case when a user submit the form, I need to **scrape** more than one page.

My code seems like that

```
app.get('/lookup', function (req, res) {

var pagesToScrape = [];
var callbackCounter = 0;
var items = [];

var callback = function(){
    if(pagesToScrape == callbackCounter){
        res.render('list', {
            title: "Hello World",
            items: items
        });
    }
    callbackCounter++;
}

var pageAResolver = function() {
    request.get({
            uri: 'http://a.com',
            //...
        items.push[jsonData];
        callback();
    );
}
var pageBResolver = function() {
    request.get({
            uri: 'http://b.com',
            //...
        items.push[jsonData];
        callback();
    );
}
var pageCResolver = function() {
    request.get({
            uri: 'http://c.com',
            //...
        items.push[jsonData];
        callback();
    );
}
pagesToScrape[0] = {url: "http://a.com", resolver: pageAResolver}
pagesToScrape[1] = {url: "http://b.com", resolver: pageBResolver}
pagesToScrape[2] = {url: "http://c.com", resolver: pageCResolver}

for(var i = 0; i < pagesToScrape.length; i++){
    pagesToScrape[i].resolver();
}
});
```

When all requests return I send the response to the browser. Sometimes it can take lot of time. What is the best strategy without caching to show this data faster?

I'm thinking about socket.io, maybe I can emit the data simultaneously? Guys, what do you think about it?

Cheers,
Pablo Cantero

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using https://github.com/caolan/async, a great async workflow library.

```
var async = require('async');

var pagesToScrape = [
  { url: "http://a.com" },
  { url: "http://b.com" },
  { url: "http://c.com" }
];

// `async.map` will fire off all requests simultaneously 
// and collect the results for you:

async.map(pagesToScrape, function(opts, callback) {

  request.get(opts, function(res) {
    // Do whatever analysis you need to get data from the page
    var jsonData = getJsonDataFrom(res);

    // Call callback when you've successfully scraped each page
    // The first parameter to callback is for "errors" (null if no error)
    // The second parameter is the jsonData object you want to use later.
    callback(null, jsonData);
  });
}, function done(err, items) {
  // This function gets called when all the pages are finished
  // items contains the list of jsonData returned to callback
  console.log(items.length); // -> 3

  var jsonData0 = items[0];
  console.log(jsonData0); // -> "{\"somedata":"fromthepage"...
});
```

If you're scraping a large number of pages, forEachLimit might be better - that processes the whole list of pages asynchronously, but only waiting for N pages at a time.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/mikeal/request following the example that I said. Request module is async too, for me the big deal is to create a pusher/comet/long pooling with this data. I would like to send to the response this data separately, when a I receive an answer I would like to send it to the response.